# How to get range value when have a strlen string

Tags: php

Ex: When I key in a few value, result will show range

```
I keyin a value 0007 => strlen is 4 => range is 1000 => 9999
I keyin a value 002  => strlen is 3 => range is 100 => 999
...
```

Can help me this ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable `$str_len` that stores the length of your keyed-in string, then you could generate the range as:

```
$min = "1" . str_repeat("0", $str_len - 1);
$max = str_repeat("9", $str_len);
```

If needed, you can then convert these strings to integer via `intval`:

```
$int_min = intval($min);
$int_max = intval($max);
```

Also see it at: https://eval.in/723487

Answer (score 2):

Using [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
 $string = strlen(1234);

 $min =  str_pad(1, $string, "0");     
 $max =  str_pad(9, $string, "9");

 echo $min; // 1000
 echo $max; // 9999
```